# Checking out an svn copy leads to "working copy locked"

Tags: svn, apache2, webdav, svn-checkout, locked

I have an svn server and with a working copy checked out on my local machine. I want to create another working copy on a webdav server by using the davfs (allows you to mount a WebDav service locally). When checking out a copy to the davfs it simply returns "Working copy locked". I tried to update the (empty, other than .svn) working copy directory only to be told that ". is not a working copy". Deleting the directory and trying to check out again also does not work. After searching extensively on Google I am becoming a bit frustrated with this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I also tried to do svn export with the same parameters, but this time I get "Can't change perms of file 'filename': Invalid argument